# how to create dynamic button in c# windows application

Tags: c#, windows, visual-studio, winforms

i have two layutflowpanel
1-flowpanel_category
2-flowpanel_products

**when i use nested for loop inside button click to get products from current select category another flowpanel_prd not showing that products from categorey maybe i have some mistake in the some point**

**i set inside InitialComponents this code to retrive all items from category to put it inside flowpanel_category**

```
 //get all category and set it all to flowpanel_cat
            
            FLOWPANEL_CAT.Controls.Clear();
            try
            {
                DT = clsgetcat.get_prd_categories();

                for (int i = 0; i <= DT.Rows.Count; i++)
                {
                    Extendedbutton Eb = new Extendedbutton();//with Extendedbutton this time
                    Eb.prdid = DT.Rows[i][0].ToString();//this asigns product_id to extended txtprdid
                    Eb._prdnme = DT.Rows[i][1].ToString();//this asigns product_nme to extended txtprdnme
                    Eb._myval = DT.Rows[i][1].ToString();//this asigns products to extended buttondescription

                    Eb.Name = DT.Rows[i][1].ToString();
                    Eb.Text = DT.Rows[i][1].ToString();
                    Eb.ForeColor = Color.White;
                    Eb.BackColor = Color.SkyBlue;
                    Eb.Font = new Font("Serif", 10, FontStyle.Regular);
                    Eb.Width = 100;
                    Eb.Height = 60;
                    Eb.TextAlign = ContentAlignment.MiddleCenter;
                    Eb.Margin = new Padding(5);

                    Button b = addbutton(i);
                    Eb.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.buttonclick);
                    
                    FLOWPANEL_CAT.Controls.Add(Eb);


                }

            }
            catch
            {
                return;
            }
```

**iset inside buttonclick this code to show each items from category inside flowpanel_prodcuts**

```
public void buttonclick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            FLOWPANEL_PRD.Controls.Clear();
            for (int i = 0; i <= DT.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                try
                {
                    for (int j = 0; j <= i; j++)
                    {
                        Extendedbutton Eb = new Extendedbutton();//with Extendedbutton this time
                        Eb._prdid = DT.Columns[0].ToString();
                        string prdid = ((Extendedbutton)sender)._prdid;
                        Eb._prdnme = DT.Columns[1].ToString();
                        string prdnme = ((Extendedbutton)sender)._prdnme;
                        Eb.Name = DT.Rows[j][1].ToString();
                        Eb.Text = DT.Rows[j][1].ToString();
                        Eb.ForeColor = Color.White;
                        Eb.BackColor = Color.SkyBlue;
                        Eb.Font = new Font("Serif", 10, FontStyle.Regular);
                        Eb.Width = 100;
                        Eb.Height = 60;
                        Eb.TextAlign = ContentAlignment.MiddleCenter;
                        Eb.Margin = new Padding(5);

                        Button b = addbutton(j);
                        Eb.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.buttonclick);
                        txttotalamount.Clear();
                        txtprdqty.Clear();
                        txtprdqty.Focus();
                        FLOWPANEL_PRD.Controls.Add(Eb);

                    }

                }
                catch
                {
                    return;
                }

                
                
                
            }
            txtprdqty.Focus();
        }


        Button addbutton(int i)
        {
            Extendedbutton EB = new Extendedbutton();
            EB.Name = EB._myval;
            EB.Text = EB._myval;
            EB.ForeColor = Color.White;
            EB.BackColor = Color.SkyBlue;
            EB.Font = new Font("Serif", 10, FontStyle.Regular);
            EB.Width = 100;
            EB.Height = 60;
            EB.TextAlign = ContentAlignment.MiddleCenter;
            EB.Margin = new Padding(5);
            return EB;
        }
```

**this picture show you output result but i have some mistake when i get products from each category**

[image: this is output result but i have some mistake when i get products from each category]

Comment: Most dynamic things are easier to manage in WPF, see for example https://timdams.com/2011/02/08/adding-buttons-to-databound-listbox-items-in-wpf/

Comment: but i have big project now ican't change all that works to WPF ;) but thank you for suggestion

Comment: @Shihabmohamed, based on your code, I have some questions. First, can you tell me the relationship between product and category? In your code, I can not see it. Second, It will be better for you to provide the related code about DT. Finally, what is your desired result and what error or exception you meet?

Comment: i have Datatable use it to get data from stored procedure this Datatable DT i'll used for them category and products

Comment: You can set the breakpoint and click the magnifier icon to show the datatable. Like   []: https://i.stack.imgur.com/71b7I.png Also, please tell me what mistake you meet.